# Increment values in a list of lists starting from 1

Tags: python

I have a list of lists e.g `[[0, 0], [4, 0], [2, 0], [5, 3], [0, 1]]`

My desired output is `[[0, 0], [1, 0], [2, 0], [3, 4], [0, 5]]`

That is, I wish to modify the list such that if the value is not zero, I set it to the count, which starts at 1 and increments by 1 for each non-zero value. If it's 0, I keep it as 0.

How do I go about this? I started by indexing using `enumerate` but it's harder than I thought.

Here is what I have done: `w` generates the initial list. This is not my full code because it is too long to post.

```
w = [[i if i != l else 0 for i in x] for x in c]
print(w)
inc = 1
lx = []
gg = []
for i in w:
   if i[0] or i[1] !=0:
      g = w.index(i)
      gg.append(g)
      lx.append(i)
for x in gg:
   for i, v in enumerate(w):
       if x==i:
          if
          print(x, i, v)
```

Thank you

Comment: are sublists always pairs or do you need handle arbitrary lists

Comment: hmm sounds interesting. It will be worth knowing how you extend to arbitrary list of lists that are not pairs. Do you mind?

Comment: @Starter See my answer. It works for arbitrary list of lists too.

Comment: @Starter updated answer, though comperhension are often faster than map which is a relic of functional programming in Python. Google code style recommends against nested comprehensions. Not sure what is their stance on double map or mixing them with comprehensions.

Answer (score 3):

This would also work, probably more pythonic and shorter, using a list-comprehension:

```
from itertools import count

lst = [[0, 0], [4, 0], [2, 0], [5, 3], [0, 1]]
counter = count(1)

lst = [[next(counter) if x != 0 else 0 for x in sublst] for sublst in lst]
# [[0, 0], [1, 0], [2, 0], [3, 4], [0, 5]]
```

Learn more about how `itertools.count` works [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.count), meanwhile here is a small snippet for a better understanding:

```
>>> import itertools
>>> c = itertools.count(1)
>>> next(c)
1
>>> next(c)
2
```

Comment: I upvoted yet think you need add assignment, the question was how to change the list

Comment: @Serge Sure. I've made the changes now. Thanks for the note!

Answer (score 1):

I think you're over-complicating this. If either elem is 0, you don't need to touch it. If it's something else, increment the count and stick it in the right place.

```
nums = [[0, 0], [4, 0], [2, 0], [5, 3], [0, 1]]
count = 0
for i,(a,b) in enumerate(nums):
  if a != 0:
    count += 1
    nums[i][0] = count
  if b != 0:
    count += 1
    nums[i][1] = count

print nums
```

Output:

```
[[0, 0], [1, 0], [2, 0], [3, 4], [0, 5]]
```

Answer (score 0):

If your sublists are two element you can get rid of enumerate

```
from itertools import count
counter = count(1)
lst = [[0, 0], [4, 0], [2, 0], [5, 3], [0, 1]]
for pair in lst:
    pair[0] = next(counter) if pair[0] else 0
    pair[1] = next(counter) if pair[1] else 0
print(lst)
```

For longer or variable sublists you may use either enumerate, map or list comprehension

```
from itertools import count
counter = count(1)
lst = [[0, 0], [4, 0], [2, 0], [5, 3], [0, 1], [0, 1, 3, 3, 3], [3]]
for sublist in lst:
    sublist[:] = map(lambda x: (next(counter) if x else 0), sublist)
    # slice assignment is 'in-place' assignment



from itertools import count
counter = count(1)
lst = [[0, 0], [4, 0], [2, 0], [5, 3], [0, 1], [0, 1, 3, 3, 3], [3]]
for sublist in lst:
    for i, element in enumerate(sublist):
        sublist[i] = next(counter) if element else 0
```

Comment: Enumerate does help. Am trying to learn how it works. If you do not mind a little explanation of what you did will help. I understood perfectly what @pushkin did

Comment: In most of cases enumerate is replacement for traditional from to loop. Python do no t have it for areason. Better just loop over elements, unless you can have resort to enumerate.

Comment: ok, enumerate is great, just was extraneous in your code (for short sublists)